# Get value of selected View in ViewSwitcher

Tags: android, list, viewswitcher

I'm using a `ViewSwitcher` to switch between two Views (as it is supposed to be used).

Here's the `ViewSwitcher` code :

```
final ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher = new ViewSwitcher(getApplicationContext());

                TextView t = new TextView(this);
                [...]
                t.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        viewSwitcher.showNext();
                    }
                });

                viewSwitcher.addView(t,
                        new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f));

                final String key = (String)map.keySet().toArray()[n];

                if(key.contains("EditText"))
                {
                    EditText e = new EditText(this);
                    [...]
                    e.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                            viewSwitcher.showPrevious();
                            return true;
                        }
                    });

                    viewSwitcher.addView(e,
                            new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f));
                }
                else if (key.contains("Spinner"))
                {
                            Spinner spin = new Spinner(getApplicationContext());
                            [...]
                            spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                                    if(adapterView.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0)
                                        viewSwitcher.showPrevious();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                                }
                            });

                            viewSwitcher.addView(spin,
                                    new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f));
                }
```

The fact is that I tried to put the ViewSwitcher in a List to get the values later.

(As it worked before when I was only using EditText), But it don't really work Because I can't get the values of what is written in the Views of the `ViewSwitcher`.

So here's my question : **Do you know how to get the value of the view that is currently selected in the ViewSwitcher so I can add it to a List to use it later ?**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getCurrentView()` method to get currently displayed view.

To get Value from view, Cast the view and get text from that view.. Like,

```
EditText temp = (EditText) viewSwitcher.getCurrentView();
String s = temp.getText().toString();
```

you can check type of current view and than get property what you want.

```
View v = viewSwitcher.getCurrentView();
if (v instanceof EditText) {
     //code...
} else if (v instanceof Spinner) {
     //code...
}
```

Comment: I did knew getCurrentView() was existing but it worked, I just did it a bit different.
I put the ViewSwitcher in the list and after that when I wanted to get the value I used getCurrentView() in another function to get the values depending of what type of View it was.
Thanks dude !

Comment: Are you want to get type of View ?

Comment: Check My Updated Answer. It may be help you.

Comment: Your first answer already helped me enough, I just readapted a little bit to my requirements, thanks a lot for your time !